# How to print a new line in an Entry box?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a GUI app where I have a Entry box. when I click a button some text is print in this entry box. when I click twice 2nd text is printing after the first text. I want to print the second text under the first text. How  can I do that?

I tried to print that new line with `"\n"`, but it's not working.

```
e2 = Entry(root, width=50, borderwidth=5)
e2.place(relx=0.3,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.3,relheight=0.2)

def bur1(num):
    e2.insert(0,"BURGER1 = 10$")
```

It's always printing that text after the first text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Entry` widget can only show a single line. If you want multiple lines you will need to use a `Text` widget if you want it to be editable, or a `Label` widget if it's just for display. You will need to insert a newline character whenever you want to start a new line.